How to set bounds for x-axis with scottplot library?
To draw a graph in my winform application, i decided to use the ScottPlot library (version 5.0.36). I don't understand how to set the bounds of the X-axis. I would like to always display values from 0 to N in the X axis.
I am using a FormsPlot and DataLoggers to store and update data. All the DataLoggers share the X axis. I set the FormsPlot limits and DataLoggers in the following way:
//Set the Plot x-axis limits as follows
formsPlot.Plot.Axes.SetLimitsX(0, 1000, formsPlot.Plot.Axes.Bottom);

...

DataLogger logger = formPlot.Plot.Add.DataLogger();

logger.ManageAxisLimits = true;
logger.AxisManager = new Slide
{
 Width = 1000,
 PaddingFractionX = .2,
 PaddingFractionY = .2,
};

LeftAxis Yaxis = formPlot.Plot.Axes.AddLeftAxis();
logger.Axes.YAxis = Yaxis;

...

//coordinates are read from a json file
logger.Add(coordX, coordY);

By setting the limits as just described, I don't understand why my x-axis limits go from about -600 to 400.
example of the graph with the wrong limits

Setting a Slide AxisManager overrides your axis limits. Intentionally, since the point of the AxisManager is to slide along new data into frame as it is added.
If you set the width of the AxisManager to 1000, it will make sure it ends at the last point. Then it will include 1000 units before that point. I think you probably want to set the axis manager to Full and then change it to Slide once you reach 1000 units from the origin.

Thanks for the suggestion!
So you suggest that I set the DataLogger to ViewFull and when I reach the limit I set the AxisManager to Slide.

If you want a fixed Axis all the time that doesn't change you can use LockedVertical/Horizontal Rules or if you want it to expand with your data logger you can simply set the Plot.Axes.ContinuouslyAutoscale = true; or even call the AutoScale every time you insert new data.
